# Procedural generation of an infinite map made up of 1's and 0's

Tags: c#, random

This is my function to procedural generate an infinite random map of 1's and 0's it only calculates what you can see at the time and when the view moves it calculates the next rows.

Complexity is the size of the view that is on the screen e.g. if complexity = 7 then the view on the screen is a grid 7x7.

It works fine but how can I tidy this up, simplify the code and make it more elegant?

```
void CreateMap(){
    if(complexity%2==0) {
        complexity--;
    }

    if (randomseed) {
        levelseed=Time.time.ToString();
        Debug.Log ("Random");
    }

    psuedoRandom = new System.Random(levelseed.GetHashCode());
    offsetx=psuedoRandom.Next();
    levellocation=psuedoRandom.Next();
    offsety=psuedoRandom.Next();
    level = new int[complexity,complexity];
    for (int x=0;x<complexity;x++){
        for (int y=0;y<complexity;y++){
            level[x,y]=RandomReturn(x+offsetx,y+offsety);
        }
    }
}

int RandomReturn(int x, int y){
    psuedoRandom = new System.Random(x*y*levellocation.GetHashCode());  
    return (psuedoRandom.Next (0,2));
}
```

An example of moving right

```
void MoveRight(){
    offsetx++;
    for (int x=0;x<complexity-1;x++){
        for (int y=0;y<complexity;y++){
            level[x,y]=level[x+1,y];
        }
    }

    for (int y=0;y<complexity;y++){
        level[complexity-1,y]=RandomReturn(complexity-1+offsetx,y+offsety);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the whole code? It would give us more context to give a better review :)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is minor, but you should not stuff all your code together without spaces like:

```
for (int y=0;y<complexity;y++){
    level[complexity-1,y]=RandomReturn(complexity-1+offsetx,y+offsety);
```

Because spaces help differentiate tokens at a first glance, I suggest one space on each side of each operator.